Picard's Theorem for Linear First Order Differential Equations
Problem: Let $I$ be an interval and $x_0\in{I}$. Let $p:I\to\mathbb{R}$, $q:I\to\mathbb{R}$ be two continuous functions. Show there exists a unique differentiable function $f:I\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x_0)=y_0$ and $$f'(x)+p(x)f(x)=q(x).$$
I was able to prove that there was a solution given by $$f(x):=e^{-\int_{x_0}^x{p(s)ds}}\biggr{(}\int_{x_0}^x{e^{\int_{x_0}^t{p(s)ds}}q(t)dt}+y_0\biggr{)},$$ but when trying to prove uniqueness I got stuck. I see that you can use separation of variables but the textbook I'm reading through doesn't include that method so I don't know any of the rigour behind it. Besides that I can see no other way to solve the problem.
Thanks for any help.

Suppose $f_1,f_2$ are solutions, then $f=f_1-f_2$ satisfies the homogenous equation and with $\phi(x) = e^{\int_{x_0}^x p(s)dx} f$, we see that $\phi'(x) = 0$ and so $f(x) = 0$.

I see, so the idea is that if we have $z'+p(x)z=0$ the there is a solution given by the  integral expression I solved for which simplifies to $\phi(x)=z(x)e^{-\int_{x_0}^x{p(s)ds}}$. Because $\phi'(x)=0$ and $z(x_0)=0$ then $z(x)=0$ for all $x\in{I}$. Is this correct?

Well, you have a $-$ sign there which doesn't work, but that is the general idea. This only works for linear systems, of course.

I don't really understand where $\phi$ comes from.

I don't know what you mean. I defined $\phi$ and showed that it is identically zero. It follows from that that $f$ is identically zero.

I understand, sorry for the delay. My computer is being really slow and weird. Thank you for the help :)
